# Trying to slide an entire div off the page and slide a new one onto the page. Console is logging but div is not moving. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is this javascript function is not moving the div .poop out of the screen:

```
    $('#placeHolder').mouseup(function() {
        console.log(answeredCorrectly);
        if (answeredCorrectly === true) {
            $('.poop').animate({left: '-50%'}, 500);
        }
    });
```

The div does not want to move, have a feeling it has something to do with me changing the .html. I remember reading somewhere that this was bad practice. Maybe when I add these classes to #placeHolder something does not translate over. Im unsure. My vision is to keep the bottom bar stationary, the entire div off the page and replace it with a new div (I have yet to create). Also if you have anymore tips I'd really appreciate it, I am just learning. This is filler fluff because according to this notification on the side my post is mostly code.

```
    var $square = $('.square');
    var $china = $('#chinaBox');
    var $checkAnswer = $('#checkAnswerWrapper');
    var answeredCorrectly = false;


     $('.square').on('click',function(){
        $('this').removeClass('selectedSquare');
        $(this).addClass('selectedSquare');
        });

    function resetButtonIfIncorrect() {
        answeredCorrectly = false;
        $('#checkAnswer').toggleClass('incorrectAnswer');
        $('#checkAnswer').removeClass('correctAnswer');
        $('#placeHolder').removeClass('animated slideInUp').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
        $('#reviewText').removeClass('animated slideInUp').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
        $('#checkAnswer').html('Incorrect');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#checkAnswer').toggleClass('incorrectAnswer');
            $('#checkAnswer').css('background', '#FFFFFF !important');
            $('#checkAnswer').html('Submit');
        }, 2000);

     }

    $('#checkAnswer').on('click', function() {
        if ($china.hasClass('selectedSquare') === true) {
            answeredCorrectly = true;
            $(this).removeClass('incorrectAnswer');
            $(this).addClass('correctAnswer');
            $(this).html('Correct!');
            $('#reviewText').html('中(zhōng) 国(guó), which literally means "middle kingdom", is how you say China in Mandarin.')
            $('#placeHolder').html('<div id = "nextButton">Next</div>');
            $('#placeHolder').addClass('buttonWrapper');
            $('#placeHolder').addClass('animated slideInUp');
            $('#reviewText').addClass('animated slideInUp')

        } else {
            resetButtonIfIncorrect();
        }
    });

    $('#placeHolder').mouseup(function() {
        console.log(answeredCorrectly);
        if (answeredCorrectly === true) {
            $('.poop').animate({left: '-50%'}, 500);
        }
    });



    <div class = "poop">

        <h1>How do you say "China"?</h1>

        <div class = "squareWrapper">
            <div class="square" id = "americaBox"> 
                <div class = "textInSquare" > 美国 / Měiguó </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="square" id = "franceBox"> 
                <div class = "textInSquare" > 法国(Fàguó)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="square" id = "japanBox">
                <div class = "textInSquare" > 日本 (Rìběn)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="square" id = "chinaBox">
                <div class = "textInSquare" > 中国 (Zhōngguó)</div> 
            </div>
    </div>


        <div id = "checkAnswerWrapper"> 
            <div id = "checkAnswer">Submit</div>
        </div>

        <div id = "reviewPlusNextLesson">
            <div id = "reviewPlusNextLessonWrapper">
                <p id= "reviewText"></p>
                <div id = "placeHolder">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div id = "bottomBar">
    </div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src = "../javascript/mandarin_lesson_1.js"> </script>


    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #0047E4 0%, #00A6FF 100%);
        background-size: auto 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    @font-face { font-family: Fipps; src: url('fipps-regular-copy.otf'); 
    } 

    @font-face {font-family: HongKong; src: url('hongkong.ttf');}


    h1 {
         padding-top: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        font-family: Fipps;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .squareWrapper {
         width: 80%;
         margin: 50px auto;
    }

    .square {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
        /* Rectangle 6: */
        background: #FFFFFF;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(88,88,88,0.50);
        border-radius: 2%;

    }

    .square:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .selectedSquare {
        outline: 3px dashed white;
        outline-offset: -10px;
    }

    #chinaBox {
        background-image: url("../images/chinaBox.png");
        background-size: 110%;
        background-position: center;
    }

    #japanBox {
        background-image: url("../images/japanBox.png");
        background-size: 110%;
        background-position: center;
    }

    #franceBox {
        background-image: url('../images/franceBox.png');
        background-size: 110%;
        background-position: center;
    }

    #americaBox {
        background-image: url('../images/americaBox.png');
        background-size: 110%;
        background-position: center;
    } 



    .textInSquare {
        width: 100%;
        height: 15%;
        background: #e6ffff;
        position: relative;
        top: 85%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;

    }

    #checkAnswerWrapper {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    #checkAnswer {
        padding-top: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 30px auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }


    .correctAnswer {
        background: #00ff80 !important;
    }

    .incorrectAnswer {
        background: #ff1a1a !important;
    }

    #reviewPlusNextLesson {
        position: absolute;
        top: 75%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: #E2E0E2;
        z-index: inherit;
        vertical-align: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
     }

    #reviewPlusNextLessonWrapper {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #reviewText {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    .buttonWrapper {
        float: left;
        width: 130px;
        height:30px;
        border: solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 15px;

    }

    #nextButton {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: center;

    }

    #bottomBar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 75%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: #E2E0E2;
        z-index: -1;
        vertical-align: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
     }
```

Comment: are you seeing the `console.log` output after the mouse up event?

Comment: that i am fine commenter

Comment: Will you please reduce your code to  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to narrow  the scope of the question to something a little easier  to digest?

Comment: ```.poop { position: 'relative' }```

Comment: @izsi is correct, add `position: 'relative'` to .poop